# Using D3 and blobs to render svg to image

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make a reverse captcha of sorts, in the end I want to be able to input long lines of text, up to 500characters, and run some basic captcha like obfuscation on the words but still be readable. But I also want an image generated that can be downloaded, not an svg.

I have managed to create the effect for the text and render an svg, and I have found an example for using d3 to render it to a datauri and blob to image. I have been trying to insert the svg into the place where the example d3 rendering is happening, but I don't think I am doing it right.

heres my working text2captcha gen with part of the non-working d3/svg/blob to image, I'll quote the html

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJRLdx

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  stroke: #000;
  fill-opacity: .8;
}

</style>
<body>
  <center>
  <h1>text2Captcha gen</h1>
  </br>
  <textarea placeholder="put your text here please"></textarea>
  </br>
  <button id="gen">gen</button>
  </br>
    <div id="svg"></div>
    <button id="save">Save as Image</button>
    <div id="svgdataurl"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


  <svg width="250" height="75">
    <text x="25" y="45" fill="black" id="text" filter="url(#warp)" style="font-size:34px;">test</text>
    <filter id="warp">
      <feMorphology radius="3" operator="dilate" />
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0.75 0.2" />
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge result="text">
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.023" numOctaves="2" result="warp" id="turb" />
      <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="60" in="text" in2="warp" id="sdm" />
    </filter>
  </svg>

<script>
  var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("idm")

d3.select("#save").on("click", function(){
  var html = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

  //console.log(html);
  var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
  var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">'; 
  d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);

});
</script>
```

^heres the js for that

```
$(function () {
  var rnum, rnum2
  $("button").click(function () {
    $("#text")
      .text($("textarea")
            .val());
    rnum = Math
      .floor((Math.random() * 80) + 40);
    $("#sdm").attr("scale", rnum
                   .toString());
    rnum2 = Math
      .floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    $("#turb")
    .attr("numOctaves", rnum2
          .toString());
  });  
});
```

and heres the link to the working d3 blob to image. I'll quote this html too.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvZpLX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  stroke: #000;
  fill-opacity: .8;
}

</style>
<body>
    <div id="svg"></div>
    <button id="save">Save as Image</button>
    <h2>SVG dataurl:</h2>
    <div id="svgdataurl"></div>

    <h2>SVG converted to PNG dataurl via HTML5 CANVAS:</h2>
    <div id="pngdataurl"></div>

    <h2>SVG converted to PNG dataurl via HTML5 CANVAS and then converted into a filename using :</h2>
    <div id="pngdataurl"></div>

    <canvas width="960" height="500" style="display:none"></canvas>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var m = 5, // number of series
    n = 90; // number of values

// Generate random data into five arrays.
var data = d3.range(m).map(function() {
  return d3.range(n).map(function() {
    return Math.random() * 100 | 0;
  });
});

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(m))
    .rangePoints([0, height], 1);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y0(function(d) { return -d / 2; })
    .y1(function(d) { return d / 2; });

var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + y(i) + ")"; })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", area);




d3.select("#save").on("click", function(){
  var html = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

  //console.log(html);
  var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
  var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">'; 
  d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image;
    image.src = imgsrc;
    image.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

      //save and serve it as an actual filename
    binaryblob();

      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.download = "sample.png";
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

       var pngimg = '<img src="'+a.href+'">'; 
       d3.select("#pngdataurl").html(pngimg);

      a.click();
    };

});


function binaryblob(){
    var byteString = atob(document.querySelector("canvas").toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")); //wtf is atob?? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.atob
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var dataView = new DataView(ab);
    var blob = new Blob([dataView], {type: "image/png"});
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var newurl = DOMURL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var img = '<img src="'+newurl+'">'; 
  d3.select("#img").html(img);
}
</script>
```

**thanks so much for even looking at my thread, im not the best at coding.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection is wrong. When you execute

```
var html = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("version", 1.1)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .node().parentNode.innerHTML;
```

the `parentNode` is the `<center>` element, and its `innerHTML` is everything on your page, not just the `<svg>` element. You can do the whole process much more concisely with the [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) interface:

```
var svgNode = d3.select('svg').node();
var html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgNode);
```

This will also take care of the `xmlns` attribute (the `version` is not needed).

The second part is that `btoa()` is not a file converter, but an encoder. The difference is that the browser decodes it back to a SVG even before it displays it. That goes against what you want to achieve. You can use the code from the example that you are following, or look at [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas#Example) that is different in detail but achieves basically the same, namely converting the SVG to a raster image.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH SIR. That helped me render to image!